# How to detect changes in form control array in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I am working on Angular 4 project. I have a requirement to detect the changes of form control array. e.g. I have a form control array named providers, how to detect its changes?

```
export class CustomFormArray {
 public form: FormGroup;

 constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
      this.form = _fb.group({
           providers: _fb.array([])
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to register the element inside of providers array as another group in order to detect it.

Comment: can you please explain it?

Comment: What are the element of providers ?

Comment: It build on run time, its not possible to register  first

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`FormArray` extends `AbstractControl` so it has `valueChanges` property which emits chanes.

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  providers: this.fb.array([]),
});
(this.form.get('providers') as FormArray).push(new FormControl('', Validators.required));
(this.form.get('providers') as FormArray).push(new FormControl('', Validators.required));

(this.form.get('providers') as FormArray).valueChanges.subscribe(values => {
  console.log(values);
});
```

In your template:

```
<input *ngFor="let field of form.controls.providers.controls;" [formControl]="field">
```

The `values` in subscribe will return a array with value of each input field when any of changes(grammatically or from UI).

In case of if there are `FormGroup` in `FormArray` nothing changes. just use following component code.

```
(this.form.get('providers') as FormArray).push(this.fb.group({
      'name': '',
      'age': ''
    }));
```

and template will be:

```
<div *ngFor="let field of form.controls.providers.controls;" [formGroup]="field">
  <input formControlName="name" placeholder="name">
  <input formControlName="age" placeholder="age">
</div>
```

here is [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yFDSWToK3hgTgvZMey3R)

Comment: I was try this . It works fine in the case of form control but it doesn't detect changes in form control array. Am surprise why?

Comment: I updated my answer now `valueChanges` is on FormArray and it's working perfectly fine. Could you explain more about your problem

Comment: Yes, I will explain, I have a providers form control array. on run time it contains a record of a provider on index 0. when I change the provider. Its remove the index and recreate it with new provider detail. But my problem is that valueChanges not detect changes in this array. I also tried your updated code. But same problem exist.

Comment: Please update your question with more code. May be there are some problem in how you are doing this.

Comment: I had solved it myself. There is problem that I remove and add form control array whenever the value change. That's why it doesn't detect changes.

Comment: If valueChanges callback is not working you can trigger it manualy using ```this.form.controls.providers.updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: false, emitEvent: true });```

Comment: What can I do to have the subscription emitting only the control that was updated/changed? I'd conform to isolating only the emitting group ...

Answer (score 2):

Is similar as how you do it for normal form group. Whenever you initialize form group of your form array, just emit/subscribe change event your form group of your form array.

here is the sample.

```
 export class CustomFormArray {
     public form: FormGroup;

     constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
          this.form = _fb.group({
               providers: _fb.array([])
          });

      this.providers.push(this.createprovidersFormGroup())
      }

    createprovidersFormGroup(){
          let form = this._formBuilder.group({
                         abc: "abc"


                     });

              form.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
                  console.log('Form changes', data)
              });

         return form;
        }
```

Comment: I already try this out. But valueChanges not work in case of form control array